# Webpack hot-reload set correctly in publicPath, but hot-middleware looks up hot-update in the wrong path

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server, hot-reload

I have an express server that setup a hot-update file at the address  `localhost:8080/static/xxx.hot-update.json`. So far so good.

("/static" is the devServer’s publicPath.)

On the frontend side I have this line in my js : `require("webpack-hot-middleware/client?reload=true")`

But it tries to look up the hot-update file in wrong place ! It uses the current url, and not "/static". If my page is localhost:8080/foo, it’ll try to fetch `localhost:8080/foo/xxx.hot-update.json` which obviously fails.

If I try to add a path :`require("webpack-hot-middleware/client?path=/static/&reload=true")`
I’ll have a 404 error : `cannot find localhost:8080/static/`

I know I’m missing a tiny parameter… but I can’t find what it can be

thanks a lot in advance for any help you can give :)

best !

Answer (score 0):

The missing bit was that I needed to add the same `publicPath`as everywhere else `output:{}`settings of webpack’s config

Comment: can you explain a bit more what you did?